# Cannot get WSO2 to work using membershipScheme=AWS

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2

I'm running WSO2 AM 1.10.0 on to Amazon EC2 nodes of the same region/zone. One of them is a manager node, the other worker node.

When running them using membershipScheme=WKA, everything works ok. When trying membershipScheme=AWS, both servers register correctly to the cloud but do not interact with each other. I verified the AWS parameters in axis2.xml are correct, and opened ports 5700-5800 to ALL.

My WKA configuration is this:

***Manager node (WKA)***

```
<parameter name="membershipScheme">wka</parameter>
<parameter name="localMemberPort">5701</parameter>
<parameter name="localMemberHost">ec2-M</parameter>
<groupManagement enable="true">
    <applicationDomain name="wso2.apim.domain"
                           description="APIM group"
                           agent="org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastGroupManagementAgent"
                           subDomain="worker"
                           port="5757"/>
</groupManagement>
<members>
    <member>
        <hostName>127.0.0.1</hostName>
        <port>5701</port>
    </member>
    <member>
        <hostName>ec2-GW</hostName>
        <port>5702</port>
    </member>
</members>
```

***Worker node (WKA)***

```
<parameter name="membershipScheme">wka</parameter>
<parameter name="localMemberPort">5702</parameter>
<parameter name="localMemberHost">ec2-GW</parameter>
<groupManagement enable="true">
    <applicationDomain name="wso2.apim.domain"
                       description="APIM group"
                       agent="org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastGroupManagementAgent"
                       subDomain="mgt"
                       port="5757"/>
</groupManagement>
<members>
    <member>
        <hostName>ec2-M</hostName>
        <port>5701</port>
    </member>
    <member>
        <hostName>127.0.0.1</hostName>
        <port>5702</port>
    </member>
</members>
```

In this mode everything works ok, and in manager log I see the gateway worker member joining the cluster:

```
Managing group application domain:wso2.apim.domain, sub-domain:mgt using agent class org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastGroupManagementAgent
Cluster domain: wso2.am.domain
Using wka based membership management scheme

Added member: Host:127.0.0.1, Remote Host:null, Port: 5701, HTTP:-1, HTTPS:-1, Domain: null, Sub-domain:null, Active:true
Added member: Host:ec2-GW,    Remote Host:null, Port: 5702, HTTP:-1, HTTPS:-1, Domain: null, Sub-domain:null, Active:true

Local member: [cf971938-ae01-42f7-84c1-563943ea1570] - Host:10.1.0.87, Remote Host:null, Port: 5701, HTTP:8281, HTTPS:8244, Domain: wso2.am.domain, Sub-domain:mgt, Active:true
Elected this member [cf971938-ae01-42f7-84c1-563943ea1570] as the Coordinator node

Added member: Host:10.1.0.87, Remote Host:null, Port: 5701, HTTP:8281, HTTPS:8244, Domain: wso2.am.domain, Sub-domain:mgt, Active:true
Application member Host:ec2-M, Remote Host:null, Port: 5757, HTTP:8281, HTTPS:8244, Domain: wso2.apim.domain, Sub-domain:mgt, Active:true joined application cluster

Member joined [a9268bd0-de59-47eb-bd90-69e6e3ef82c8]: ec2-GW/10.1.0.193:5702
Added member: Host:10.1.0.193, Remote Host:null, Port: 5702, HTTP:8280, HTTPS:8243, Domain: wso2.am.domain, Sub-domain:worker, Active:true
```

Now changing to AWS mode:

***Manager and Worker node (AWS)***

```
<parameter name="membershipScheme">aws</parameter>
<parameter name="accessKey">...</parameter>
<parameter name="secretKey">...</parameter>
<parameter name="securityGroup">...</parameter>
<parameter name="region">eu-west-1</parameter>
```

(left everything else untouched)

```
Managing group application domain:wso2.apim.domain, sub-domain:mgt using agent class org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastGroupManagementAgent
Cluster domain: wso2.am.domain
Using aws based membership management scheme

Group management local member for domain [wso2.apim.domain],sub-domain [mgt] UUID: e8847f8c-b6c4-434d-9c3c-7eb8ceca59f2. Host:ec2-M, Remote Host:null, Port: 5757, HTTP:8281, HTTPS:8244, Domain: wso2.apim.domain, Sub-domain:mgt, Active:true

Local member: [2740f020-ca36-4e41-a94c-996d4c1a4fee] - Host:10.1.0.87, Remote Host:null, Port: 5701, HTTP:8281, HTTPS:8244, Domain: wso2.am.domain, Sub-domain:mgt, Active:true
Elected this member [2740f020-ca36-4e41-a94c-996d4c1a4fee] as the Coordinator node

Application member Host:ec2-M, Remote Host:null, Port: 5757, HTTP:8281, HTTPS:8244, Domain: wso2.apim.domain, Sub-domain:mgt, Active:true joined application cluster
```

As you can see from the log, there is no indication of the worker.

Furthermore, changes done in the manager are not consumed by the worker.

In the worker node:

```
Managing group application domain:wso2.apim.domain, sub-domain:worker using agent class org.wso2.carbon.core.clustering.hazelcast.HazelcastGroupManagementAgent
Cluster domain: wso2.am.domain
Using aws based membership management scheme

Group management local member for domain [wso2.apim.domain],sub-domain [worker] UUID: d034e9b0-b101-4d78-af44-d3e4a28ba0fd. Host:ec2-GW, Remote Host:null, Port: 5757, HTTP:8280, HTTPS:8243, Domain: wso2.apim.domain, Sub-domain:worker, Active:true

Application member Host:ec2-GW, Remote Host:null, Port: 5757, HTTP:8280, HTTPS:8243, Domain: wso2.apim.domain, Sub-domain:worker, Active:true joined application cluster

Local member: [50961848-8d78-412f-b83f-01dc8c7ad3bf] - Host:10.1.0.193, Remote Host:null, Port: 5702, HTTP:8280, HTTPS:8243, Domain: wso2.am.domain, Sub-domain:worker, Active:true
Elected this member [50961848-8d78-412f-b83f-01dc8c7ad3bf] as the Coordinator node
```

I checked with telnet: ports 5757, 5701 and 5702 are accessible b/w the two nodes.

Any ideas why the two nodes are not communicating?

---

***Follow up #1 based on comments***

Added tag to both nodes

> $ aws ec2 create-tags --resources ec2-M ec2-GW --tags Key=component,Value=gateway

Verifiy with describe-instances:

> $ aws ec2 describe-instances

```
...
"Tags": [
                    {
                        "Value": "gateway", 
                        "Key": "component"
                    }
]
...
```

Modified axis2.xml, for both ec2-M and ec2-GW:

```
    <parameter name="localMemberPort">5701</parameter>
    ...
    <parameter name="accessKey">...</parameter>
    <parameter name="secretKey">...</parameter>
    <parameter name="securityGroup">...</parameter>
    <parameter name="region">eu-west-1</parameter>
    <parameter name="tagKey">component</parameter> 
    <parameter name="tagValue">gateway</parameter>
```

Still no communication b/w the nodes

---

***Follow up #2 after further investigation***

Using Hazelcast REST API, I noticed that in WKA mode, each member is registered in Hazelcast of both nodes

On manager, running http://ec2-M:5701/hazelcast/rest/cluster:

```
Members [2] {
    Member [ec2-M]:5701 this
    Member [ec2-GW]:5702
}
```

On worker, running http://ec2-GW:5702/hazelcast/rest/cluster:

```
Members [2] {
    Member [ec2-M]:5701 
    Member [ec2-GW]:5702 this
}
```

While in AWS mode, each node see only itself.

On manager, running http://ec2-M:5701/hazelcast/rest/cluster:

```
Members [1] {
    Member [ec2-M]:5701 this
}
```

On worker, running http://ec2-GW:5701/hazelcast/rest/cluster:

```
Members [1] {
    Member [ec2-GW]:5701 this
}
```

Comment: Reading the doc again, seems i have to specify port 5701 to both nodes, and not 5701/5702 as i did here. is this whats causing the problem?

Comment: You can use different ports as the localMemberPort in servers. In your configurations, I see tagKey and tagValue parameters are missing. Shall we add those? For a gateway cluster you can use key as component and value as gateway. Official docs - https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Setting+up+a+Cluster+in+AWS+Mode

Comment: Tried adding the tag, but it did not help. See "Follow up #1 based on comments" addition to my original question.

Comment: Note follow-up #2 with some further hazelcast information.

Comment: Can you try disabling groupManagement?

Comment: Disabling it gives the error "Node could not join cluster. A Configuration mismatch was detected: Incompatible joiners! expected: tcp-ip, found: aws Node is going to shutdown now!".

Comment: I'm considering using WKA with range of IP (e.g. 1.10.0.1-255) instead of AWS. It seems to work, except for taking ~5 minutes for the manager to identify that worker node has joined. Not sure why is it taking so long, and if this is configurable, but at least after 5 minutes it works ok.